What are the assumption in the DTS paper
In the original  Duration Times Spread paper from Arik Ben Dor
, Lev Dynkin, Jay Hyman
, Patrick Houweling
, Erik van Leeuwen and Olaf Penninga
, the authors define a change in spread as follows:

Then they say that if you assume that spread are proportional to spread levels, we can defined the % change in spread as follows:

I don't fully understand why we can divide by sJ the market term.
